# how to set additional attributes to the table that OneToMany creates automatically and retrieve or update them later?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

When I create two entity tables and set **one to many** mapping between them , hibernate automatically creates a table which stores the primary keys of those two entity tables in each row.
how can i add other attributes to this automatically generated table and then use them later?